# Does Transaction.Commit() closes the underlying connection as well. C#

Tags: c#, database

After Transaction.Commit()` the connection property of my transactions gets set to null. I wonder what happens to the connection object, does it get Closed too?

I want to make sure the connection gets closed too. Please suggest.

So In Calling method I am coding as followed.

```
System.Data.SQLClient.SQLTransaction trans = null;
System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection oConn = null;
trans = oConn.GetIWSTransaction();

trans.commit();

and in GetIWSTransaction() as
Private System.Data.SQLClient.SQLTransaction m_oIWSTransaction = 
null;
Private System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection m_oIWSConnection = null;

if(this.m_oIWSConnection.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
this.m_oIWSConnection.Open();
this.m_oIWSTransaction = this.m_oIWSConnection.BeginTransaction();

return this.m_oIWSTransaction;
```

Now the question is, does `trans.commit()` in calling method terminates the connection as well or it just sets it to null. If it just sets it to null then how can we handle connection closure?(any alternative than Using block)

Comment: share your code, I guess you are using some thing like using (SqlTransaction tran = connection.BeginTransaction())
{ and that is equal to try {..} finally dispose.

Comment: Source code is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/R/2020d30f68510cce.html), you can see the connection is not disposed

Comment: "Close" is an overloaded term in this context. When you Close() an ADO.NET connection it is returned to the connection pool, it remains an open connection to the database, ready for re-use. I'm not sure if you care about that distinction or not.

Comment: @mytham- I am not using the Using block since it does not implement IDisposable interface.

Comment: @ShashikantTantarpale please give more details then. like a [mcve]. What classes are you using? What framework? What version? etc. There is no magic one answer to rule them all.

Comment: @JHBonarius Apologies for the delay in response, I am learning this code. I have edited the question to give you a better picture. Please let me know if any more details are needed.

Answer (score 3):

No it does not.
If you want to close the connection, the suggested way is to put the connection in a `using` block. E.g.

```cs
using (DbConnection db = GetDbConnection())
{
  db.Open();
}
```

The connection will get closed when the object is disposed.

edit: like Charlie said, the transaction should ideally also be enclosed in a using block.

You can even use a [`TransactionScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope)

#edit:
If you are learning, follow a guide. E.g. [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/).

Also, these kinds of low level SQL access (SqlClient and ADO.NET) is not suited for starters. You should look into leaning [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/), or maybe [Dapper](https://dapperlib.github.io/Dapper/) (although the latter is already for more advanced/experienced developers).

Back to your code. It's design doesn't seem well organized. Try to follow the idiomatic design and keep things together.

And about the `using` blocks. [`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection) derives from `DbConnection`, thus is `IDisposable`. Same for `SqlTransaction` and `DbTransaction` and `IDisposable`.

So your code could look like this:

```cs
using System.Data.SqlClient;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...connection string...))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction"))
    {
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        command.CommandText = ...your SQL...;

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                // a closed connection.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the transaction needs a `using` also

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the using statement is used to work with an object that implements the IDisposable interface. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ShashikantTantarpale The [`DbConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection) implements the `IDisposable` interface. And "closes" the connection when disposing.

Comment: Re: "Also, these kinds of low level SQL access (SqlClient and ADO.NET) is not suited for starters." - I disagree. It may take more time to gain some fluency, but afterwards you at least understand, what actually happens - starting from high-level frameworks you learn frameworks, but may not understand basic. Just my opinion :)

Comment: @Arvo I've seen so many raw SQL mistakes by newbies over the years. SQL injection attacks still make up a significant part of the vulnerabilities found every year. Of course one should learn SQL, but you should start learning to drive in a formula 1 car. (Also I rarely see companies use raw SQL from c#, and if they do, it's not the junior developers who are allowed to write it.)